# How to use Java's Big Decimal in this context?

Tags: java

My code:

```
//Ramanujan's Method of Calculating Pi

public class Main {

    private static final double a1 = 9801.0;
    private static final double a2 = 1103.0;
    private static final double a3 = 26390.0;
    private static final double a4 = 396.0;
    private static final int loops = 2;
    private static double asum;

    public static double factorial(double n) {
        if(n==0) return 1;
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
       //The calculation 
        for(int i=0;i<=loops;i++) {
            asum += ((2*Math.sqrt(2))/a1)*((factorial(4.0*i))*(a2 + (a3 * i)))/(((Math.pow(factorial(i),4.0)))*(Math.pow(a4,(4.0 *i))));
        }
        System.out.println(Math.pow(asum,-1));
    }
}
```

I am sorry for the poor readability, but I am on my phone at the moment, so it is hard to edit code. I am trying to get my program to print out Pi using ramanujans method of calculating, yet I am only familiar with doubles, and after attempting to use Big Decimal, I'm still stuck. How do I use big decimal in this context? Thanks!

Attempt:

```
import java.math.*;
//Ramanujan's Method of Calculating Pi
public class Main{

private static final BigDecimal a1 = new BigDecimal(9810);
private static final BigDecimal a2 = new BigDecimal(1103);
private static final BigDecimal a3 = new BigDecimal(26390.0);
private static final BigDecimal a4 = new BigDecimal(396.0);
private static final BigDecimal con1 = new BigDecimal(2*Math.sqrt(2));
private static final int loops = 2;
private static BigDecimal asum;

public static BigDecimal factorial(BigDecimal n){
    if(n==n.ZERO) return n.ONE;
    return n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(n.ONE)));
}

public static BigDecimal calc1(int i){
    BigDecimal ret = new BigDecimal((factorial(4*i));
    return ret;
}

public static void main(String []args){
    for(int i = 0;i <= loops;i++){
        asum += (con1.divide(a1)).multiply(calc1(i)).multiply((a2 + (a3.multiply(i))).divide(((Math.pow(factorial(i),4.0))).multiply(Math.pow(a4,(4.0 *i))));
    }
    System.out.println(Math.pow(asum,-1));
}
```

}

Comment: I tried using my variable asum as a big decimal, and then substituted all of the operations with of the default functions of Big Decimal

Comment: Can you post that code?

Comment: I assume that when you tried to substitute BigDecimal, you ran into problems. What were they? (And, yes, post the code as Mshnik suggests.)

Comment: Try to avoid comparing `double` values to 0 using `==` as you do here in `factorial`.  It won't matter in this particular case; but here, where you know the values are always integers, you should be using `int` instead.  In general, roundoff errors may cause `double` values to be very small but non-zero even when you know they "should" be zero.

Comment: Edit: Added attempt at Big Decimal. The for loop is giving me a headache...

Comment: You need to initialize `BigDecimal asum = BigDecimal.ZERO;` and you need to replace `asum += ...` with `asum = asum.add(...)`

Comment: Also `new BigDecimal(2*Math.sqrt(2))` might be problematic due to the inaccuracy of `double`. Use `BigDecimal.valueOf(2*Math.sqrt(2))` instead.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the inputs :-) This program has definitely taught me a lot about memory and data/object types in java

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from `double`s to `BigDecimal`s is nearly mechanical. Here is how you can do that in a few simple steps:

- Add an import of `java.math.BigDecimal` at the top of your program
- Replace all variables of type `double` with variables of type `BigDecimal`
- Replace all value initializations with calls of `BigDecimal` constructors; use fields `ZERO` and `ONE` for zero and one.
- Rewrite expressions using `BigDecimal`'s methods.

You may also add constants to save some time, for example

```
BigDecimal sqRootOfTwo = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(2));
```

The last step is the trickiest one: for example, if you have an expression that looks like this

```
double d = a * b + c;
```

it would have to be rewritten like this:

```
BigDecimal d = a.multiply(b).add(c);
```

Division is tricky, too, because you must specify the desired precision. However, overall conversion should be relatively straightforward: if you managed to get your program to work using `double`s and you follow the conversion correctly, the result should simply work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the detailed instructions! I'll try it now :-)